# How to make a relative Layout app responsive without too many code changes?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have an app in relative layout, inside there is:

1) A vertical linear layout having a switch and 2 `editText`.

2) A horizontal linear layout below the vertical one with 2 buttons.

It is working fine on a galaxy A8 phone but the horizontal linear layout is overlapping on bottom `editText` on smaller screen phone.

I need some guidance on how to make it responsive without too much code changes as my interface design technique is pretty poor.

Thanks for your help.

I tried to convert it to `Constraint-Layout` but it makes my user interface worse. The app stopped responding from it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
    android:clipChildren="false">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="15dp">

        <Switch
            android:id="@+id/switch1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:text="French to English"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:checked="true"
            android:thumbTint="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:trackTint="@color/colorAccent" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/pname"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="225dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:maxLength="100"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_border_edittext"
            android:ems="15"
            android:gravity="top"
            android:hint="Enter your text to translate here..."
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:padding="10dp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/target"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="225dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:maxLength="100"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_border_edittext1"
            android:ems="15"
            android:gravity="top"
            android:hint="Your translated text will appear here..."
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:padding="10dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="15dp">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnsave"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Save" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btntranslate"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Translate" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try setting the height to 190dp for both EditTexts in the vertical LinearLayout

```
android:layout_height="190dp"
```

and also their margingTop value to 15dp

```
android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
```

which will fit the minimum  screen size of an Android device which is 426x320

Comment: Thank you very much it is working on both phones now. TYVM